# Changing site name in django template?

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, django-templates

How to change site name into  django template ..

```
<title>{% block head_title_base %}{% if SITE_NAME %}{{ SITE_NAME }} | {% endif %}{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}{% endblock %}</title><br/><br/>
```

See this github [Django-Planet](https://github.com/g33ksimon/django-planet)
I forked and to do some modification . but no idea how to change the site name ..

I tried to change that in planet directory base.html but after changing also comes no changes .Currently now its showing example.com .. Any idea how to change it ?

Comment: it may be a variable in your settings.  i'd check settings.py and settings_local.py

Answer (score 11):

You can change the site name via the Django Admin in the Sites app (/admin/sites/site/).

(The default value is set to `example.com`.)

Alternatively, you can do a query on Site at the Django prompt, modify and save the model.

For more information see the [Django sites framework docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)

Comment: Ok my bad ,, Now changed thanks .. and also can you tell me how to change footer ?